# Wordpress broken dashboard with ninja-shell text

Tags: plugins, php, hacked

I am facing some strange behavior on my bluehost hosted wordpress site. Here's what I am facing:

1. I see blank white page when I browse my website in a browser
2. I was unable to access to my site using credentials. I now managed to reset my access via bluehost and found a spam user in users section of bluehost dashboard with email `...@pnpby.com`. *(I have deleted that user now)*
3. I see some strange text on `mysite.com/wp-login.php` page and over WP dashboard. Please check the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t13Q9.png)
4. I'm unable to make any changes to my WP dashboard. In response to any action, I I used bluehost panel to make some changes i.e. disabling some plugins and installed updates but nothing resolved the issue.

Any idea whats going on and how can I completely fix it? I was of the view that probably some of the plugins will be causing the issue but I disabled all one by one but nothing resolved the issue.

Comment: This does look like a hack, a good indicator is the directories (in the picture provided) that are just a string of random characters.  Important to keep in mind that on a shared hosting plan it doesn't even need to be your site that gets hacked, could have been another one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you found a suspicious user, there's a good chance your site has been hacked. The easiest thing to do is have the professionals take a look. At minimum, install a new security plugin and scan your site, delete suspicious files, take the time to weed out unused plugins and update everything, change your login credentials both to WP and your host. You'll need to find whatever they exploited or they'll keep getting back in.